# In MegaParsec is there a way of anding 2 parsers?

Tags: parsing, haskell

If I have a parser like:

```
notZeroOrOne :: Parser Char
notZeroOrOne = noneOf ['0' , '1']
```

Is there a way I can combine the rules of another parser like digitChar so I can get a parser that will only pass if both parsers would pass?

Something like

```
biggerThanOne :: Parser Char
biggerThanOne  = digitChar && notZeroOrOne
```

Comment: As I understand, you want `biggerThanOne` to succeed precisely if both `digitChar` and `notZeroOne` would succeed starting from precisely the same point? This is possible (see lookAhead), but in general not really sound - in this case, both parsers parse a single char, and return precisely that char. What if one parser did something with the char first? The output of both parsers would not be the same - which output is returned? What if one consumes more or less output than the other, but both succeed? Where is the final position? You should solve this problem with `oneOf ['2'..'9']` instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As user2407038 suggests in the comments, it's achievable using the `lookAhead` function.

```
biggerThanOne :: Parser Char
biggerThanOne =
  lookAhead digitChar *> notZeroOrOne
```

However, the parsers are sequential by nature, so it's both more efficient and comprehendable to apply the sequential logic. E.g., using the `Monad` instance of `Parser`:

```
biggerThanOne :: Parser Char
biggerThanOne =
  do
    c <- digitChar
    if c /= '0' && c /= '1'
      then return c
      else unexpected "Not bigger than one"
```

Or `MonadPlus`:

```
biggerThanOne :: Parser Char
biggerThanOne =
  mfilter (\c -> c /= '0' && c /= '1') digitChar
```

which can be refactored to use the `Ord` instance of `Char` and pretty much clearly express your intent:

```
biggerThanOne :: Parser Char
biggerThanOne =
  mfilter (> '1') digitChar
```

Answer (score 2):

In the uu-parsinglib there is an amb combinator, which gives you all possible parses. You can use this to see whether you get both parses. If you get only a single parse you can use a monad to fail

p `pAnd` q = amb (p <|> q) >>= \ r -> if length r == 2 then return ... else pFail